# PIC32MX ICSP wiring

Tags: pic, icsp

I was looking to use a PIC32MX series microcontroller on a project. It is currently in the mail, but I thought I would try to understand the wiring for power and programming before it arrived. I had planned on using a PICKit 3 to program the device over the ICSP line, but I'm having some trouble understanding the wiring of the MCLR. Here are the designs I have come across:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJYP6A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

According to Figure 2-2 on page 46 of the [reference manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61156H.pdf) for the device family the connection circuit should look something like the first circuit design. According to the [Microchip wiki](http://microchip.wikidot.com/8bit:mclr) it should look like the second circuit. The third design comes from Figure 2-4 in the [PICKit 3 User's Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PICkit_3_User_Guide_51795A.pdf) and the final design comes from Figure 1 in the [Microchip ICSP Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/30277d.pdf). The design I have seen most people using is the third one, but I am unsure if it would be better for some reason to use one of the others. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in the past I have used Option 1, although all of them will probably work ok.

The advantage of Option 1 is that it is the most protected from ESD and other transients on the programmer reset pin and the switch.

---

Option 4 is intended for the case where the programmer is providing a high \$V_{PP}\$ (possibly 13V) to the \$\overline{MCLR}\$ line.

Related: [ICSP Circuit: Vpp (13V) and Vdd (5V) on Pic microcontroller MCLR pin](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31507/icsp-circuit-vpp-13v-and-vdd-5v-on-pic-microcontroller-mclr-pin)

Answer (score 0):

I am using option 3, just because it is simplest.

But here I combined options 1 and 4:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFdrzG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It combines ESD protection (from option 1), and blocks 13V to get to Vdd (from option 4)